How to solve "entity type XY has no key defined"?
I am making an application in mvc .net core and when scaffolding the data model I get this error:

entity type Users has no key defined, define the key for this entitytype

Does Anyone Know How to Solve this Error?
I have tried everything, but I think the solution has to come from VB.Net Because the Solutions from C# have Not Worked for Me
Public Class Usuarios
    <Key>
    Public Id As Integer
    Public Nombre As String
    Public Clave As String
    Public FechaAlta As DateTime
    Public Comunidad As String
    Public comunidades As SelectListItem
    Public Ciudad As String
    Public Rol As Integer
End Class

Greetings

It would help if you showed us the Users class any configuration code related to it. Note: there is no need to repeat the tags (like VB.NET) in the title.

Hello, this is the users class in VB.NET and when doing the Scafolding, it gives me the error that I said Before
Public Class Usuarios
<Key> Public Id As Integer

Public Nombre As String

Public Clave As String

Public FechaAlta As DateTime

Public Comunidad As String

Public comunidades As SelectListItem

Public Ciudad As String

Public Rol As Integer

End Class

Please, click "Edit" and add the class to your question next time. It is completely unreadable in the comments section and all information to the question should appear in the question itself.

I think, that the problem is, that you declared fields instead of properties. Since a property with the name Id or <entity name>Id, e.g., UsuariosId, will automatically be recognized as key, the <Key> attribute is not required in this case.
Public Class Usuarios
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Nombre As String
    Public Property Clave As String
    Public Property FechaAlta As DateTime
    Public Property Comunidad As String
    Public Property comunidades As SelectListItem
    Public Property Ciudad As String
    Public Property Rol As Integer
End Class

See also:

Keys - EF Core
Automatically implemented properties (Visual Basic)

